# "ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized."

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

***Here is the code:***

```
 string str = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:/Users/charlyn_dale/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/LMS/WindowsFormsApplication2/Accounts.accdb;Persist Security Info=False");
            OleDbCommand conn = new OleDbCommand(str);
            con.Open();
            string query  = "insert into Account ([Username],[Password],FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,Age,Section,Gender,Address,AccountStatus) values('" + txt1.Text + "','" + txt2.Text + "','" + txt4.Text + "','" + txt5.Text + "','" + txt6.Text + "','" + txt7.Text + "','" + txt8.Text + "','" + cmb2.Text + "','" + txt9.Text + "','" + cmb1.Text + "')";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
            conn.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Registration Success!");
            con.Close();
```

and the error is:

> Connection property has not been initialized

Comment: are `con` and `conn` different?

Comment: Yes, as @PrashanthBenny points out, you need to change 'con.Close' and 'con.Open' to use 'Conn'

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 main issues in your Access DB connection:

1. `OleDbConnection` connection string property has not initialized when opening OLE DB connection (note that `con` is different from `conn` in this context).
2. The connection string wrongly assigned to variable `conn` which declared as `OleDbCommand`, use `OleDbConnection` instead.
3. The connection string data source path seems invalid by using slash sign for directory separator (assuming target file exists in Windows folder), use backslash escape sequence (`\\`) or single backslash with literal string instead (e.g. `@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\......"`).

Hence, the correct connection sequence should be like this:

```
string str = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\charlyn_dale\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\LMS\\WindowsFormsApplication2\\Accounts.accdb;Persist Security Info=False");

using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(str))
{
    conn.Open();

    // security tips: better use parameter names to prevent SQL injection on queries
    // and put value checking method for all textbox values (sanitize input)
    string query = "insert into Account ([Username],[Password],FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,Age,Section,Gender,Address,AccountStatus) values ('" + txt1.Text + "','" + txt2.Text + "','" + txt4.Text + "','" + txt5.Text + "','" + txt6.Text + "','" + txt7.Text + "','" + txt8.Text + "','" + cmb2.Text + "','" + txt9.Text + "','" + cmb1.Text + "')";
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
    {
        conn.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    ... // other stuff
    conn.Close();
}
```

NB: `using` statements added due to OLE DB connection should be disposed immediately after usage to free up resources.

Similar issues:

[get an error as ExecuteNonQuery:Connection property has not been initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376979/get-an-error-as-executenonqueryconnection-property-has-not-been-initialized)

[ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized (access database)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294828/executenonquery-connection-property-has-not-been-initialized-access-database)

[ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253286/executenonquery-connection-property-has-not-been-initialized)